# How to create a single jar file of multiple projects in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, executable-jar

So I have 3 different projects in Netbeans. When I run my main project, it interacts with other 2 projects and starts the application. I need to pass this application to another team, so I was thinking if I could bundle it together in a single jar file using which the other team can run this application.

I know about "packaging" option which I can use from my main project "properties". However, I am not able to run this application using the jar file created in /project/dist as there are other dependencies.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I cannot give the code to the other team, hence looking for a workaround.

Comment: why don't you just package the dependencies in the jar as well

Comment: @Ishnark I thought the dependencies should be packaged when I clean and build my main project. Not sure why its not happening

Comment: There are two ways you can mention dependencies. You can either put the dependencies on the same level as your project and then link them via manifest or you can extract the dependencies and put them in your jar. It sounds like you're doing option 1 but want to do option 2

Comment: @Ishnark - yes, I want to do option 2. I'll try putting together all dependencies along with the main project jar file and then execute the jar file and see if it works. Thanks!